# PHP validation errors display on a blank page, not the one that i designed

Tags: php, html, css

When I clicked on submit button, the validation works but it doesnt display on the designed page. But it is still in the same file directory

[the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iII5r.png)
[validation output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJ3rW.png)

it is still the same file but with different display

```
function addDonation($donation)
{

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        var_dump($_POST);

        $errors = [];

        if (isset($_POST['salutation'])) {
            $donation->user_salutation = $_POST['salutation'];
        } else {
            $errors['salutation'] = 'Salutation is required';
        }

        if (isset($_POST['gender'])) {
            $donation->user_gender = $_POST['gender'];
        } else {
            $errors ['gender'] = 'Gender is required';
        }

        if (empty($_POST['name'])) {
            $errors['name'] = 'Name is required';
        } else {
            $donation->user_name = $_POST['name'];
        }

        if (empty($_POST['nric'])) {
            $errors['nric'] = 'NRIC or Passport is required';
        } else {
            $donation->user_idno = $_POST['nric'];
        }

        if (empty($_POST['dob'])) {
            $errors['dob'] = 'Date of birth is required';
        } else {
            $donation->user_dob = $_POST['dob'];
        }

        if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
            $errors['email'] = 'Email is required';
        } else {
            $donation->user_email = $_POST['email'];
            if (!filter_var($donation->user_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                $errors['email'] = 'Invalid email format';
            }
        }

        if (empty($_POST['address'])) {
            $errors['address'] = 'Address is required';
        } else {
            $donation->user_address = $_POST['address'];
        }

        if (empty($_POST['town-city'])) {
            $errors['town-city'] = 'Town/City is required';
        } else {
            $donation->user_address_town = $_POST['town-city'];
        }

        if (empty($_POST['postcode'])) {
            $errors['postcode'] = 'Postcode is required';
        } else {
            $donation->user_address_postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
        }

        if (empty($_POST['telephone'])) {
            $errors['telephone'] = 'Telephone number is required';
        } else {
            $telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
            $pattern = '/^\d{3}-?\d{3}-?\d{4}$/'; // 123-456-7890 format
    
            if (!preg_match($pattern, $telephone)) {
                $errors['telephone'] = 'Invalid phone number format';
            } else {
                $donation->user_mobileno = $telephone;
            }
        }



        if (empty($errors)) {
            try
            {  
                $conn = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
    
                // Check connection
                if ($conn->connect_error) {
                    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                }
            
                $sql = "INSERT INTO donations (user_salutation, user_name, user_idno, user_gender, user_dob, user_email, user_address, user_address_town, user_address_postcode, user_address_country, user_mobileno, donation_refno, payment_amount) 
                VALUES ('$donation->user_salutation', '$donation->user_name', '$donation->user_idno', '$donation->user_gender', '$donation->user_dob', '$donation->user_email', '$donation->user_address', '$donation->user_address_town', '$donation->user_address_postcode', '$donation->user_address_country', '$donation->user_mobileno', '$donation->donation_refno', '$donation->payment_amount')";
    
                $result = $conn->query($sql);
                if ($result === TRUE) {
                    $ret = "";
                } else {
                    error_log("SQL ERROR : ".$sql);
                    $ret = "Error occur while placing order. Please try again later.";
                }
    
                $conn->close();
            }
            catch(Exception $e)
            {
                $ret = "Error occur while placing order. Please try again later";
            }
    
            return $ret;
    
        } else {
            foreach ($errors as $error) {
                echo '<div class="error-message">
                <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display=\'none\';">&times;</span>
                <strong>' . $error . '</strong>
                </div>';
            }

            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

idk what went wrong. already tried restarting my web server and clear cache. i want the validation errors to appear on the designed page. i already adjust the css and html but nothing happen.

help me..

Comment: We see the var_dump and the echo statements we would expect to see based on the code you've posted. Presumably, you're calling addDonation  before you try to format the rest of the page but you haven't shared that code. The PHP exit function stops execution of the script, not just the method, so when you call this method it dumps the contents of $_POST, echos the formatted errors, and stops executing.

Comment: what alternative can i use besides exit function? since if i didnt put it, it will show the error on a white page for a few second then proceeds to go to the next page

Comment: Are you posting back the form to a different url than its own page? That would make your life more difficult. But we can't tell from what you've shown. Please [edit] your question to provide a [mre] of the situation so we can see how things are structured

Comment: _"since if i didnt put it, it will show the error on a white page for a few second then proceeds to go to the next page"_ - nothing of what you have shown us so far, would cause any "proceeding to the next page" -so that must be happening outside of `addDonation` somewhere. Your function should rather still _return_ a value, and then the logic around this gets modified to _not_ redirect elsewhere, when errors occurred.